# Twilio sandbox for development

Tags: twilio

We are using an SMS messaging service to send SMS to customers. In order to test and develop the things do we have any Twilio sandbox? We don't want to test all the things directly in PROD Twilio account.

Searched for a solution for the sandbox in Twilio but was not able. As per the article, we saw that there is an option only for WhatsApp only.

Comment: The sandbox for WhatsApp is a solution Twilio offers to get you started quickly with development, as otherwise you'd have to go through a long process to integrate with WhatsApp.
This is specific to WhatsApp and there's no need for this workaround for Twilio Phone Numbers to text or call. I'd recommend using the test credentials IObert suggested.

Answer (score 2):

The [Test Credentials](https://www.twilio.com/docs/iam/test-credentials) are pretty helpful if you want to test a function and does an API call without actually sending a SMS.